# AngularJs Call a Directive method without any event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a Directive :

```
myDirectives.directive('myRating', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  template: '<div> <ul style="margin : 0px">' +
              '<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)" ng-click="toggle($index)"              id=$index readonly="false">' + '<img src="star.png">'                  
              '</li>' +
            '</ul></div>',

  scope: {
    .
    .
    .
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {       
       // if myId exists in array tab[]           
       if (tab.indexOf(scope.myId+"") != -1) {
          //get a value val

          toggle(val);   //*******Call function toggle ***********
        }

    scope.toggle= function(val) {
          scope.ratingValue = val + 1;          
          // set clicked rating value and change ui as well
    }
```

Now, the error is =>  toggle is not defined.
Although the code can be repeated here as well, but to avoid redundancy, is there a way I can call toggle?
Thanks

Comment: Call it as `$scope.toggle(val);`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. didn't strike to use it..you can add it outside so that I can mark it answer

Comment: One doubt in extension to it, the directive template i am using is isolated, but when I call toggle to set scope.ratingvalue as val for that scope, it sets the max value for the entire scope and not just that template.. any idea why that is happenning ?

Comment: With insufficient code, its not clear but perhaps because your directive uses bi-directional binding. You can edit this one or post a different question.

Comment: will post as a new one.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by CodeHater, scope.toggle( did the trick.. Marking the answer... Thanks 

 but this triggered a new error... as followed up in [Load value from db on rendering directive template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376626/load-value-from-db-on-rendering-directive-template)